# Entity Framework: Loading 2nd level navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following three tables:

Clients:
  id
  clientname

Projects:
  id
  clientid (int ref to Clients.id)
  projectname
  projectstatus (int ref to ProjectStatuses.id)

ProjectStatuses:
  id
  statusname

I select a single client fine, and when needed I load the selected clients projects like this:

selectedClient.Projects.Load();

but how do I have it also load the project status name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
selectedClient.Projects.ProjectStatuses.Load()
```

**Edit**

It's a One-to-many relationship i guess,

this should work

```
selectedClient.Projects.First().ProjectStatuses.Load()
```

or you could also load it directly in your query with

```
context.Clients.Include("Projects.ProjectStatuses");
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not working. It only seems to want to allow me to go one level into the navigation properties.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do your attempts throw an error, or just silently fail to load the nested properties? What about stringing the Include statements, e.g. `context.Clients.Include("Projects").Include("Projects.ProjectStatuses")`

Comment: I am getting closer. What it is doing now is listing the class name instead of the value. Like this: "Project.Data.ProjectStatus", You are right, there will be one client and a bunch of projects, all with different statuses.

Comment: @djacobson I am not using the Include to load the projects because unless the user clicks on a client I do not want them loaded. I am loading the projects for the client that is selected only after selection is made.

Comment: @Shane The given example should only load ProjectStatuses for the first client project in the list...